# Why do options listed in \LoadClass not affect?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I have listed `dvipsnames` (or other options) in `\LoadClass` with the hope I don't need to specify `dvipsnames` (or other options) in `\documentclass`.

Apparently this does not work as what I expect. It means, I need specify `dvipsnames` in `\documentclass` even though this option has been specified by default in `\LoadClass`. It looks like the options defined in `\LoadClass` get ignored.

## MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{dummy.cls}
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{dummy}[2015/10/21 v 0.01 description]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[% the default options
    dvipsnames,
    12pt,
]{article}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\def\test{\textcolor{Red}{It is a test.}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}


% try remove dvipsnames 
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{dummy}
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

## Questions

What is the correct way to define default options when making user defined class?

Comment: `article` does not know what to do with `dvipsnames` this way. I think you have to specify `dvipsnames` to be an option of `dummy.cls` two and pass the parameter explicitly to the package with `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnams}{xcolor}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The options to `\LoadClass` don't become global options, so they're not passed to every loaded package; so you have to add `dvipsnames` manually, if you want it to become global.

The option `dvipsnames` is not defined in `article.cls`, so it does nothing, but it doesn't raise an error either, because of how options are dealt with in class files.

```
\ProvidesClass{dummy}[2015/10/21 v 0.01 description]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[% the default options
    12pt,
]{article}
\@expandtwoargs\in@{dvipsnames}{\@classoptionslist}
\ifin@
  % dvipsnames has been used as a global option by the user, do nothing
\else
  % append dvipsnames to the list of global options
  \ifx\@classoptionslist\@empty
    \g@addto@macro\@classoptionslist{dvipsnames}
  \else
    % with a comma if the list is not empty
    \g@addto@macro\@classoptionslist{,dvipsnames}
  \fi
\fi
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\def\test{\textcolor{Red}{It is a test.}}

\endinput
```

Now calling either `\documentclass{dummy}` or `\documentclass[dvipsnames]{dummy}` will result in `\@classoptionslist` to contain `dvipsnames`, so upon loading `xcolor` the `dvipsnames` option will be passed to it.

However, I'm not sure this is a good thing to do.