# Cannot set draftmode via LoadClass in custom class

Tags: documentclass-writing, class-options, draft

I have a custom class that loads article. I can set certain default parameters, but the draft option seems to be ignored. I have the following in my custom class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sdy-article}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, draft]{article}
```

This indeed gives me a 10pt a4paper, but it is not in draft mode. If I set the draft mode in the document where I load the custom class like so:

```
\documentclass[draft]{sdy-article}
```

It does go into draft mode. The thing is, I want to have some conditional in my custom class to determine whether draft mode should be set or not and then pass that on.

I have tried passing it like this as well to no avail:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{draft}{article}
```

---

### EDIT

Adding a full example here to show what is happening.

sdy-article.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sdy-article}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt, a4paper, draft]{article}
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{sdy-article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-golden}\qquad
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}

\noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}

\noindent\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-c}

\noindent\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

this gives the following output:
[image]

As you can see, images are rendered as if draft mode was not set.
The weird thing is that `\overfullrule` *is* in fact set to 5.0pt as you would expect in draft mode.
When I add the draft option in main.tex (`\documentclass[draft]{sdy-article}`), it does go full draft mode:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show an example where draft was not passed on.

If I run

```
\documentclass{sdy-article}

\begin{document}

\showthe\overfullrule
\end{document}
```

Then the terminal shows

```
> 5.0pt.
l.5 \showthe\overfullrule
                         
? x
No pages of output.
```

showing that the `article` class draft mode is active, setting the overfull box rule to 5pt rather than the default 0pt.

---

With the modified example, the question is now rather different. `draft` *is* passed on to the `article` class but it is not passed to graphicx and it is not a *global document option* as it is not in the explicit user-supplied list of options passed to `\documentclass` therefore `graphicx` does not see `draft`
Your class could do

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}
```

Then if `graphicx` is loaded it will see `draft`

Comment: Right, I see that too. However, the resulting document has all images rendered as if the document wasn't in draftmode. Also, `\ifraft` from the package ifdraft will execute as is draftmode was not set

Comment: I have added a full example to my question

Comment: @SeeDoubleYou ah that's a different question, I'll add a note to my answer

Comment: @SeeDoubleYou updated answer

Comment: Thanks David, however, my question is not about graphicx specifically, my example was merely... an example. The thing is, when I set draft as an option in main.tex, it is set and used everywhere. So graphics are in draft, `\ifdraft` renders the draft case, etc. However, when I set it in `\Loadclass` or with `\PassOptionsToClass`, this does _not_ happen. I want to know why that is, since I really don't want to pass draft manually to all packages. Also, I have quite some things relying on `\ifdraft`

Comment: @SeeDoubleYou there is no global definition of draft, `article` class for example has no `\ifdraft` defined (nor has `graphicx`) however any package code sees the global option list as if it was passed explicitly so if the user uses `draft` on `documentclass` then the `draft` option is passed to all packages including `graphicx` If you have an `\ifdraft` defined then some package must be defining it that you have not shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109455/discussion-between-seedoubleyou-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 0):

To those getting here later, let me show you how I "solved" this in the end. @DavidCarlisle's answer will remain as the accepted answer since it explains what going wrong and why. This is just for any future readers that may want to accomplish something similar.

Again, in short, I want to set the draft option "globally" once, like what would happen if you add it as an option to documentclass. I want to do this in my custom class, based on some conditional.

David mentioned in the chat that although it no being a supported interface, adding draft to `\@classoptionslist` "by hand" could do the trick. Then I came across this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274057/45330
And I did pretty much the same thing:

```
[...]
<pseudo: conditional states we need to set draft>
  \@expandtwoargs\in@{draft}{\@classoptionslist}
  \ifin@
  % draft has been used as a global option by the user, do nothing
  \else
    % append draft to the list of global options
    \ifx\@classoptionslist\@empty
      \g@addto@macro\@classoptionslist{draft}
    \else
      % with a comma if the list is not empty
      \g@addto@macro\@classoptionslist{,draft}
    \fi
  \fi
}{}
<end conditional block>
```